# Delay javascript execution? Not sure what I have to do in this case

Tags: javascript, html

Basically, I'm using the accordion thing in Bootstrap 5, but because I have a lot of text, inside the body of the accordion, it takes longer to close the first one when opening the second one.
What I want is for it to maybe delay the execution of a JS function so that it'll wait until the first accordion header has fully closed, and then run the function.

This is basically what it looks like: https://prnt.sc/17wa079
when pressing Header 1, I have `onclick=goToHeader1` and that's basically just using scrollIntoView() so that Header 1 is at the very top of the screen. If you don't close Header 1 before opening header 2, it's all weird and only shows the bottom of header 2 at the top (where it should show actually show "Header 2", it shows the bottom part of the body of Header 2) or it just doesn't even show Header 2 at all.

So I figured that perhaps if you could delay `onclick="goToHeading2()`
you could wait for Header 1 to fully close (give it like 1 or 2 seconds) then execute function goToHeading2() and then that would fix it.

Just haven't figured out how to delay it by 1 or 2 seconds, so if anyone could suggest how, that would be great. Or if anyone has a better way to doing it, that would be even better.

Comment: `onclick="setTimeout(goToHeading2, 2000)"` might work, if I'm understanding your quesiton correctly? https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to delay your js code you can do it using :

```js
await new Promise( resolve => setTimeout( resolve, 1000 ));
// this part of your code will be executed after 1 sec
```

But I don't think this a good idea as the time taken to run the previous function will be different on different devices.

I think you are calling `Element.scrollIntoView` on the full accordion, it will better if you call scrollIntoView on just the `accordion-header` block.

Moreover, scrollIntoView has some options like alignToTop which you can use for better results.

```js
element.scrollIntoView();
element.scrollIntoView(alignToTop); // Boolean parameter
element.scrollIntoView(scrollIntoViewOptions); // Object parameter
```

In your case, `element.scrollIntoView(true);` will bring the best results.
You can read more on this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView).